# Monthly calendar view functionality reduced in Notes 8?

Tags: lotus-notes

In Lotus Notes 7, it was possible to scroll a calendar in a monthly view, so that it started on an arbitrary Monday and showed the next five weeks or so.  In this way one could see all of a three-week trip that spanned a month end.

In Lotus Notes 8, it appears to be possible only to show whole months, and the ability to scroll the view has been removed.

Am I correct in this, or is there a trick or setting to restore the old behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like a question to Super User forum, not coding related.

Answer (score 1):

This is true at least for all releases up to 8.5.3. 
And it cannot be customized in Designer.
In Notes 9 Beta it works as it was implemented prior to R8.

Comment: Why couldn't it be customized in Designer?  You can rewrite the entire design if you want, it just wouldn't be easy.

Comment: OK, let me correct this: to my best knowledge it cannot be customized. The calendar behaviour does not only rely on a view but also on how the view is displayed in Notes. I think this is part of the client core. Correct me if I am wrong, I would be really interested in this from a technical point of view. BTW: This feature was heavily requested at last year's Lotusphere in the Ask the product managers session. It was promised for a future release and I think this is one reason why it has been implemented in Notes 9.

Comment: Honestly, you probably know more about it than I do, customizing major features of the mailfile is beyond what I typically do anyway. I was under the impression that the mail and calendar were all database features with the client just being a wrapper that displayed them. I know there are some features that don't work in basic mode, so some of the features may be reliant on the eclipse based client though.